# Create an alias that can move a file in a directory using just the name file

Tags: lubuntu

I want an alias "recycle" and when I use recycle , I want to move  that in a directory.

Comment: Needs a lot more info no clue what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to be able to move a file to the rubbish bin using `recycle`, without fully deleting this file.

While this may be possible with an alias, it is easier to create a `recycle` function in your `~/.bashrc`. To do this, run `nano ~/.bashrc`, then go to the end of the file, and add this:

```
recycle() {
    mv "$@" ~/.local/share/Trash/files
}
export -f recycle
```

If you want the files to be moved to a different directory, then you can (optionally) change `~/.local/share/Trash/files` to a directory of your choice.

Now use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to save your edits and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.

Finally, either restart your terminal to apply the changes or apply them immediately with `source ~/.bashrc`.

Now, you can execute `recycle your_file` or `recycle /path/to/your/file` which will move your file to the rubbish bin (or a different folder of your choice, if you used a different folder in the function). Furthermore, it also works with directories and multiple files (e.g. `recycle mydirectory`, `recycle file1 file2 file3` will all work).

Comment: I want an alias "recycle" that do mv (move) a file in a directory, My argument for recycle is the file i want to move(mv).

Comment: Give me an alias example please.

Comment: Now I dont know how to save a function in bashrc

Comment: @Radu you were given an excellent answer to your otherwise vague question. Please consider showing your appreciation by accepting the answer. All details on how to include this function in your `.bashrc` are indicated in this answer. An alternative approach would be to make a very small script including exactly the same command in a folder in your PATH. An alias is not designed to do what you want to do.

Comment: alias delete="mv --target-directory='Director'"   - This is the answer